# How to infer multiple type with one generic type

Tags: typescript

This is the type I would like to describe:

```
type RenderItems<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        label: string;
        options: {
            defaultValue: T[K]['options'][current_index_of_array];
            item: (value: T[K]['options'][current_index_of_array]) => void;
        }[];
    }
}
```

In this way I will be able to call the following function:

```
const func: <T>(renderItems: RenderItems<T>) => void = (renderItems) => {}

func({
    prop1:{
        label:"example",
        options:[
            {
                defaultValue: "example string",
                item(value){
                    // value type is string because defaultValue is a string
                }
            },
            {
                defaultValue: new Date(),
                item(value){
                    // value type is Date because defaultValue is a Date
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    prop2:{
        label:"example 2",
        options:[
            {
                defaultValue: 1234
                item(value){
                    // value type is number because defaultValue is a number
                }
            },
        ]
    },
})
```

So each item function in the options array must have its type automatically recognized based on defaultValue

Comment: You can write your type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NaZaPm) but TS isn't smart enough to infer that sort of thing, due to [ms/TS#53018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53018).  You'd be better off guaranteeing such a thing by using helper functions like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxqQKW).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I had partially arrived at a solution similar to yours before reading your answer, in essence I used the same concept but without using the opts function, but I had to turn [options into an object](https://tsplay.dev/mLAaVW).

But your solution is better, since I can use an array instead of an object, so if you write an answer I will mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express the type you were looking for like this:

```
type RenderItems<T extends Record<keyof T, readonly any[]>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    label: string;
    options: XForm<T[K]>
  }
}

type XForm<T extends readonly any[]> =
  { [I in keyof T]: { defaultValue: T[I], item: (value: T[I]) => void } }

const func: <const T extends Record<keyof T, readonly any[]>>(
  renderItems: RenderItems<T>
) => void = (renderItems) => { }
```

the `XForm<T>` utility type takes an array type argument for `T` and uses a [mapped type over tuple/arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to iterate over the numeric indices `I` and map each element individually.  So `I` takes the place of your `current_index_of_array` and the whole thing will be an array without needing to put `[]` on the end.

---

**But this does not serve your intended purpose**.  TypeScript is not smart enough to infer parameter types of [context-sensitive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) callback functions inside a generic nested array/object structure like this:

```
func({
  prop1: {
    label: "example",
    options: [
      {
        defaultValue: "example string",
        item(value) {
          // ^?(parameter) value: any 
        }
      },
      {
        defaultValue: new Date(),
        item(value) {
          // ^?(parameter) value: any 
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  prop2: {
    label: "example 2",
    options: [
      {
        defaultValue: 1234,
        item(value) {
          //^? (parameter) value: any 
        }
      },
    ]
  },
});
```

There are various open issues that touch on this; the most closely related to your example code is [microsoft/TypeScript#53018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53018).  Maybe if it is implemented then this will start working as is, but for now this approach is probably not going to be very fruitful.

---

If you really want inference of those callback parameters, then this is sort of an XY problem; you thought that defining `RenderItems<T>` properly would do it, but it doesn't.  A different approach to get inference is to break this into smaller pieces for the compiler; for example, maybe each element of `options` should be the output of a function whose only job is to validate a *single* pair of `defaultValue` and `item`:

```
interface Opt<T> {
  defaultValue: T,
  item(value: T): void;
}
function opts<T>(defaultValue: T, item: (x: T) => void): Opt<T> {
  return { defaultValue, item }
}
```

Now `func()` can be defined as

```
const func: <const T extends
  Record<keyof T, {
    label: string, options: readonly Opt<any>[]
  }>>(
    renderItems: T
  ) => void = (renderItems) => { }
```

And you can call it like this:

```
func({
  prop1: {
    label: "example",
    options: [
      opts("example string", value => { }),
      //                     ^?(parameter) value: string
      opts(new Date(), value => { })
      //               ^?(parameter) value: Date
    ]
  },
  prop2: {
    label: "example 2",
    options: [
      opts(1234, value => { }),
      //         ^?(parameter) value: number
    ]
  },
});
```

Now you get inference in exactly the places you expect, and the inferred type of `T` looks like

```
{
    readonly prop1: {
        readonly label: "example";
        readonly options: readonly [Opt<string>, Opt<Date>];
    };
    readonly prop2: {
        readonly label: "example 2";
        readonly options: readonly [Opt<number>];
    };
}
```

which is also what you wanted (well, maybe you don't care about or want `readonly` but that's just an artifact of using a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters), which I used so that TS would keep track of the order and length of `options` properties... if you don't care about that you can change it).

It's not a perfect solution, obviously, since having to call `opts()` might not come naturally to people.  But at least the inference works!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA5A9jZBvAsAKCSQBcBPTJAJQmABMIAnASSIjCgB4AVJCADxdpRKEeGno12Aawgk0AMyScANEnoQQNNMAA2JJCGAkA2gF0AfGaQBeJLgKEkRgNJIAlsCTTZCziYBctvgODtogAEYQ2gFQRPTuAOYA3EHBSBhErlpQAQAaAGJiYFzO5imEAL4plfak5PmFXDz81DRCahpauvqGppZWZbaOjG4eXvKK-oN0ciAArtpEAGog2rMQAZxGjCYqrixgAQAUAG4raxtbJgCU1pbHaK40SOXPKaLAMUhys8DwAezvT7cPgCVrCUTiKQycbKVTqTQ6PQGYzmMyHAZqWgMZisbLCLFMfYcThmFI3Kx3B5PGyHTF0Qm48mWLCvPD4FLfX6HOzBGD0DAARgCPNSoQiUSQACI+OAYNoIJKlANCOlMh8AkZlQ4RakHNM5gtlqt1lKZWA5cgYnFgPFFVrgntWCczhAbjrdQ4APSepAAPQA-Ic4PRwBAWPQbqdjQFkUhALwbgCI9+0Oaoe55K+y6926-XzJYugLACAAdyQABEQCxDlcM2nCI6wM7jW7k8FvX7A8HQ+HIwXunpE63WWnU6kTANyrWHHyMAAmYVasWRALS3iy+VIWd2zMOVVZDXJ7OpXOGvsC2cAZgALFO0w2m2sWzu096A0ggyAQ5Ae0go+d+-GSbPqko66pOWrjju4H2OUVzJHg1T4O44YzIgSAAPIwEQXDMikJ75tGihTvef4mpwVwBPcjzwdUnLwBkWhpFhxJovhRr-rCDZHLwGxMr+VIURhWE4YE9hqEQsz0B4LJsS6uz7KyiF4ICRBfD8fxIACWSqcCzSCCkVAQhIYw+Co7pLhKVoJCoe7qnCHSIkJ2HImYphVBY6I7nS2JEhsZK3PxjzWO+3kMmwfEskp+B0dyKQzjAQqicEFkrmaFrbsEtl4pqwHpFAhyruulqxAkiq-i6AWRTWWrtnWdUdh+X5hgwvaEVZNpanlhxFqWFZVjW5XGpVzxXDVPr1Q4AaNd2LWDf+fUQAMkEVFO8XzklIThMuppruaG5breTEMXZOW6l157XiopHDbBh2ELVHpTV236zaRhazGAET0EtVQZrB8GegAVBthDtAiXTxYlR6g-CnR6ClO1FZK8FpmDcNHWqeJo45RiYdh7XxGYKh4+wC1mCYKMppTMMORD-IwOt0P2eD8NbRKhV7cgW7U6k2NdFlAR83ouPCcAH1feTPPlDRSCA567J4EAA)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript may not be able to infer the correct type for value, but it can be made to fail if given the wrong type. With a `RenderItems` defined like this:

```js
type RenderItems<T extends Record<string, { options: unknown[] }>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        label: string;
        options: (
                T[K]["options"][number] extends infer O ?
                O extends {defaultValue: infer V} ?
                {
                    defaultValue: V;
                    item: (value: V) => void;
                } : never : never
            )[]
        }
    }
```

The code below will helpfully fail with

> Type `(value: string) => void` is not assignable to type `(value: number) => void`.

```js
declare const func: <T extends RenderItems<T>>(renderItems: T) => void

func({
    prop2:{
        label:"example 2",
        options:[
            {
                defaultValue: 1234,
                item(value: string){
                }
            },
        ]
    },
})
```

Note that the type of `func` changed from `<T>(items: RenderItems<T>) => void` to `<T extends RenderItems<T>>(items: T) => void`, which allows it to get the value types using `O extends {defaultValue: infer V}` and then use `V` to define `item` as `item: (value: V) => void;`